# RUN conda activate not works. It always shows "restart your shell after running 'conda init' " , Dockerfile

Tags: bash, anaconda, dockerfile, conda

I'm going to build a cuda & anaconda docker file, but after trying many times, it always warning me the error.

The log of azure pipelines.

[image]
and my Dockerfile:

```
FROM rogerchen/simpledet:cuda10 as cuda
WORKDIR /app

ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
ENV PATH /opt/conda/bin:$PATH

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget git make python3-dev libglib2.0-0 libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev python3-pip \
    && apt-get clean

RUN wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-5.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/anaconda.sh && \
    /bin/bash ~/anaconda.sh -fbp /opt/conda && \
    rm ~/anaconda.sh && \
    ln -s /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/conda.sh && \
    echo ". /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    echo "conda activate base" >> ~/.bashrc

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

RUN conda update conda -y

RUN conda create -n simpledet python=3.7  -y
RUN conda init bash
RUN conda activate simpledet
RUN conda install cudatoolkit=10.
```

There is 'RUN conda init bash' before 'activate'. So hope guys give me some tips. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Interactive bash

The `conda activate` command is a bash function and only gets loaded in interactive sessions. The DOCKERFILE already does the equivalent of `conda init`, i.e., adding `conda.sh` to the `.bashrc`. However, the current SHELL `/bin/bash -c` does not load `.bashrc` - usually need a `-i` or `-l` flag for that.

### Conda activate isn't necessary

But that's all beside the point because there is no reason to have to activate the env given the current code. Instead, install all the dependencies from the start (recommended):

```
conda create -n simpledet -y python=3.7 cudatoolkit=10.
```

or at least specify the env:

```
conda install -n simpledet -y cudatoolkit=10.
```

### Environment Specification

If the environment requires more than a few packages, or needs something from PyPI, then it is best to use a YAML environment definition file and create the env through that. Example file:

**simpledet.yml**

```
name: simpledet
channels:
 - defaults
dependencies:
 - python=3.7
 - cudatoolkit=10.
 - pip
 - pip:
   - mxnet
```

You can then create the env with:

```
COPY simpledet.yml /tmp/simpledet.yml
RUN conda env create -f /tmp/simpledet.yml
```

Comment: after install cudatoolkit , I hope to install mxnet by pip3. so I don't know how to contruct the Dockfile.

Comment: It's there any way to enable 'conda init' by default?

Comment: @Echo _after install cudatoolkit , I hope to install mxnet by pip3. so I don't know how to contruct the Dockfile._ Is that package not available with Conda?

Comment: @AMC Hi, the above answer is ok for me. finally, I give up with conda, because with conda  I choose the python3 with the system.  So https://github.com/rwecho/MxNetDocker is my docker file, hope it works to you

Comment: @Echo _because with conda I choose the python3 with the system._ What do you mean?

Comment: @AMC, I did not use conda image, I take nvidia-cuda as my source image. For details in the github.